# Strange behaviour AutoCompleteTextView android in old APIs

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I have this AutoCompleteTextView and in the Android APIs 18 or bellow is behaving like the image:

[Buged AutoCompleteTextView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zsec.png)

And it should be like this:

[Normal AutoCompleteTextView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIZYR.png)

Answer (score 0):

We found out the error was related to the cradle version. We had the class path:

*classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'*

And we downgrade to:

*classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'*